# How i can put elements inline html

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my elements.

[image]

I have 3 elements in left, and 3 elements in right.
I don't really know CSS, and
i want the 3 elements in right be align with 3 elements in left.

[image]

Thank you for you time, i hope you understand what i want to do!
**My code:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://web.ryanteel.repl.co/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<style>
  .card-adryan {
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* Added */
    float: none;
    /* Added */
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    /* Added */
  }
  
  .card-header-adryan {
    padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .card-adryan {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: .25rem;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .slot-left {
    width: 18%;
    height: 57px;
    float: left;
    border-top: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-left: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-bottom: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-right: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  
  .slot-right {
    width: 18%;
    height: 57px;
    float: right;
    border-top: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-left: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-bottom: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-right: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card-adryan" style="width: 20rem;">
      <div class="card-header-adryan">
        Character
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="left-a-b">
          <div class="slot-left">

          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div class="slot-left">

          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div class="slot-left">

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="right-a-b">
          <div class="slot-right">

          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div class="slot-right">

          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div class="slot-right">

          </div>
        </div>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  <!--
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.alert-danger').hide();
        </script>
        -->
</body>
```

Comment: Use grids. Bootstrap has it's own grid classes; if you don't wanna build your own.

Comment: @SouyamaDebnath You can give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using Bootstrap so you can simply use it's css (row, col) like this:

1. Just change your classes `slot-left` and `slot-right` width to be `width: 36%;`  instead of `width: 18%;`.
2. Add `row` class to your card-body div => `<div class="card-body row">`.
3. Add `col-6` class to your `left-a-b` & `right-a-b` divs => [`<div class="left-a-b col-6">` & `<div class="right-a-b col-6">`].

so your total code should look like this:

```css
    .card-adryan {
        margin: 0 auto; /* Added */
        float: none; /* Added */
        margin-bottom: 10px; /* Added */
    }
    
    .card-header-adryan{
        padding:.75rem 1.25rem;
        margin-bottom:0;
        background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .card-adryan{
        position:relative;
        display:-webkit-box;
        display:-ms-flexbox;
        display:flex;
        -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction:normal;
        -ms-flex-direction:column;
        flex-direction:column;
        min-width:0;
        word-wrap:break-word;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        background-clip:border-box;
        border:1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        border-radius:.25rem;
        color: white;
    }
    

    .slot-left { 
        width: 36%; 
        height: 57px; 
        float: left; 
        border-top: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        border-left: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        border-bottom: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        border-right: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        opacity: 0.5;
        
    }
    
    .slot-right { 
        width: 36%; 
        height: 57px; 
        float: right; 
        border-top: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        border-left: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        border-bottom: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        border-right: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://web.ryanteel.repl.co/bootstrap.min.css">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="card-adryan" style="width: 20rem;">
              <div class="card-header-adryan">
                Character
              </div>
              <div class="card-body row">
                <div class="left-a-b col-6">
                    <div class="slot-left">

                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="slot-left">

                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="slot-left">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="right-a-b col-6">
                    <div class="slot-right">

                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="slot-right">

                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="slot-right">

                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the `display: flex` on your `card-body` and place a `space-between` for your `justify-content` setting. Add some padding to move from side.

```css
.card-adryan {
        margin: 0 auto; /* Added */
        margin-bottom: 10px; /* Added */
    }
    
    .card-header-adryan{
        padding:.75rem 1.25rem;
        margin-bottom:0;
        background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .card-adryan{
        position:relative;
        -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction:normal;
        -ms-flex-direction:column;
        flex-direction:column;
        word-wrap:break-word;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        background-clip:border-box;
        border:1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
        border-radius:.25rem;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .card-body {
      padding: 20px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    

    .slot-left { 
        width: 57px; 
        height: 57px; 
        border-top: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        border-left: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        border-bottom: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        border-right: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        opacity: 0.5;
        
    }
    
    .slot-right { 
        width: 57px; 
        height: 57px; 
        border-top: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        border-left: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        border-bottom: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        border-right: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="card-adryan" style="width: 20rem;">
              <div class="card-header-adryan">
                Character
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="left-a-b">
                    <div class="slot-left">
                      
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="slot-left">

                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="slot-left">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="right-a-b">
                    <div class="slot-right">

                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="slot-right">

                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="slot-right">

                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS grids to solve this

first, create your grid container with 9 cells (to leave the second column empty)

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>

<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

then put your first three-element  in (1, 4, 7)
the other three in (3, 6, 9)